# Query Editor and Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, query-editor

I am fetching records using a query involving _Open and _Subscribers Data views.
When I run it in Query editor, it is able to return results within 20 minutes.
The same query when run as a SQL query activity in Automation Studio, it is timing out.

SELECT a.ClientID
, a.JobID
, a.ListID
, a.SubscriberID
, a.SubscriberKey
, b.EmailAddress
, a.EventDate
, a.BatchID
From (
SELECT a.OYBAccountID as ClientID
, a.JobID
, a.ListID
, a.SubscriberID
, a.SubscriberKey
, a.EventDate
, a.BatchID
FROM _Sent a with (nolock)
WHERE a.EventDate >= DATEADD(day,-2,getdate())) a
INNER JOIN ENT._Subscribers b with (nolock)
ON a.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID

Can anyone please help me know why this is happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on a lot of factors.

1. Target DE Primary keys on the target DE Operation that your Query
   activity is doing.
2. Is it an Update or Append? Usually Updates take
   more time.
3. Try splitting the query into two sub queries and see the
   result.
4. Does your query fails during the day? If so, then try
   running it in the night when the platform is not that much in use.

The way query studio works is a bit different than Automation Studio when it comes to Target DE. Query Studio just dumps the result in a temporary table.

You can also write your query in the question for the community to better help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, Swati for a prompt explanation :D.
I am going to try to split it into sub-queries and schedule it for the night.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it resolves your query.